# If $G$ is isomorphic to $H$, then ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Aut}(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If a group $G$ is isomorphic to $H$, prove that ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Aut}(H)$.

Can someone provide a step by step solution? Explaining along the way our strategy in proving this.

Comment: Hint: Pick an isomorphism $G\to H$, and use it to define a map $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\to\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ in the most obvious way you can think of. Then (assuming you write down the right thing), it should be relatively straightforward to prove that its an isomorphism; probably easier to write down an inverse than to prove injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: Let $f\colon G\to H$ be an isomorphism. For each $\varphi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ define $\hat\varphi=f\circ\varphi\circ f^{-1}$. Do the necessary checks and it's done. Where's precisely the problem?

Comment: @AspiringMathematician Please ensure that your question is fully understandable without the title. The title's purpose is to attract people to your question (and to make it easily searchable). Once it has done that, it's job is done. The question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: It should be clear that the first thing to do is name an isomorphism between $G$ and $H$: let $h:G\to H$ be an isomorphism. Now you want to use $h$ somehow to construct an isomorphism between $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$. Suppose that $\varphi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. How could you use $\varphi$ and $h$ to construct an automorphism of $H$? There’s only one reasonable thing to try.

An automorphism of $H$ maps $H$ to $H$, so start with an arbitrary $x\in H$. Use $h^{-1}$ to find the corresponding element $h^{-1}(x)$ of $G$, apply $\varphi$ to that element to get another element of $G$, and use $h$ to find the corresponding element of $H$. This may sound a bit complicated, but it’s just a composition of functions. Then prove that the map that you’ve constructed from $H$ to $H$ really is an automorphism.

To show that every automorphism of $H$ arises in this way, just start with an automorphism $\psi$ of $H$ and use the same ideas to find a $\varphi\in\operatorname{G}$ that gets sent to $\psi$ by the map described in the preceding paragraph.

Comment: So your strategy is to basically give a diagram commuting argument.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\phi:G\to H$ be an isomorphism. A useful intuition is that $G$ and $H$ are just two manifestations of the same object, except that the group elements may have different names in the two cases. The mapping $\phi$ tells us for each element $g\in G$ which element $\phi(g)\in H$ corresponds to this element. In other words, $\phi$ tells us how to rename the elements of $G$ to obtain elements of $H$. The inverse of this isomorphism, $\phi^{-1}:H\to G$ tells us, how to get from an element $h\in H$ back to an element $\phi^{-1}(h)\in G$.

Now suppose $\alpha:G\to G$ is an automorphism. (Note that an automorphism may be regarded as "a structure-preserving renaming of the elements *within* the group".) Since we regard $H$ as just another version of $G$ with different names of the elements, we should expect this automorphism to correspond to some automorphism $\Phi(\alpha):H\to H$. But how to get this automorphism?

Remembering that we consider an element $h\in H$ to be just a renamed version of some element $g\in G$, namely $g = \phi^{-1}(h)$, we are led to the idea that we may define the desired automorphism $\Phi(\alpha)$ by simply renaming the element $h$ to "whatever it's called in $G$", then doing what $\alpha$ does, to obtain the result, and then renaming it back, to obtain "the name of the result in $H$".

If we trace what this does, we obtain: $$h\mapsto \phi^{-1}(h)\mapsto \alpha(\phi^{-1}(h))\mapsto \phi(\alpha(\phi^{-1}(h))),$$ so the automorphism $\Phi(\alpha): H\to H$ will be defined by

$$\Phi(\alpha)=\phi\circ\alpha\circ\phi^{-1}.$$

You may verify that $\Phi:\operatorname{Aut}(G)\to\operatorname{Aut}(H)$, defined in this way, is indeed an isomorphism of groups. (Note that $$\Phi(\beta)\circ\Phi(\alpha)=(\phi\circ\beta\circ\phi^{-1})\circ(\phi\circ\alpha\circ\phi^{-1})=\phi\circ\beta\circ\alpha\circ\phi^{-1}=\Phi(\beta\circ\alpha).$$)

We can visually express the definition of $\Phi$ by the following commutative diagram:

$$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\newcommand{\ua}[1]{\bigg\uparrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
G & \ra{\alpha} & G\\
\da{\phi} & & \ua{\phi^{-1}}\\
H & \ras{\Phi(\alpha)} & H\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Clearest answer among the  3, yet the least upvoted, shocking!

Answer (score 3):

If $C$ is any category with objects $x,y$ such that $x \cong y$, then $\mathrm{Aut}(x) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(y)$ as groups. Namely, if $f : x \to y$ is an isomorphism, then every automorphism $g : x \cong x$ can be "conjugated" to an automorphism $y \xrightarrow{f^{-1}} x \xrightarrow{g} x \xrightarrow{f} y$, and vice versa.